# Flash game slows down

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am almost finished with this flash game, but when I test it the game slows down overtime. I've read the script over and over. Tried to comment parts out of the script, but it still slows down.

This is my whole script:

```
//loads keyboard events
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent

var laatstelook:int = 1;
var ironbird:Boolean = false;
var laatstejump = 1;
var movebirdie:int = 2;
var birdfatigue : Boolean = false;
var birdtellery:int = 0;
var birdtelleryvertrager = 0;
var vy:Number=0;
var movement:Boolean=false;
var springen:Boolean=false;
var gv:Number=0.1;
var keyArray:Array = new Array();
var i:Number;
var leftOrrightpressed:Number=0;
var platformraak=false;
var PlatformArray:Array = new Array();
var StudioLightArray:Array = new Array();
var MovingPlatformArray:Array = new Array();
var MovingStudioLightArray:Array = new Array();
var SpeakerArray:Array = new Array();;
var birdieRespawnY = 90.1;
var birdieRespawnX = 40.75;
var campowerupPositionX = 275.3;
var speed : int = -2;
var lightspeed : int = -2;
var setmoveto = false;
var birdieAttack : Boolean = false;
var shitlist : Array = [];
var shit:ShitMissile = new ShitMissile();


var IronManMusic:Sound = new IronManSong();
var IronManChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

var backgroundMusic:Sound = new BackgroundMusic(); 
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
myChannel = backgroundMusic.play();

powerupscreen.visible = false;
powerupscreen.stop();

for(i=0;i<222;i++){
    keyArray.push([i,false]);
}
//creating multiple objects from 1 object


for (var a:int = numChildren - 1; a >= 0; a--){
    var child:DisplayObject = getChildAt(a);
    if (child.name == "platform"){
        PlatformArray.push(child);
    }
}

for (var b:int = numChildren - 1; b >= 0; b--){
    var child2:DisplayObject = getChildAt(b);
    if (child2.name == "studiolight"){
        StudioLightArray.push(child2);
    }
}

for (var c:int = numChildren - 1; c >= 0; c--){
    var child3:DisplayObject = getChildAt(c);
    if (child3.name == "movingplatform"){
        MovingPlatformArray.push(child3);
    }
}

for (var d:int = numChildren - 1; d >= 0; d--){
    var child4:DisplayObject = getChildAt(d);
    if (child4.name == "movingstudiolight"){
        MovingStudioLightArray.push(child4);
    }
}

for (var speaker:int = numChildren -1; speaker >= 0; speaker--){
    var child5:DisplayObject = getChildAt(speaker);
    if(child5.name == "speaker"){
        SpeakerArray.push(child5);
    }
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,checkKeysDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,checkKeysUp);
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, UpdateScreen);
function UpdateScreen(event:Event):void{

    /*trace(birdie.x, "birdie");
    trace(vcam.x);*/

    //moves platform 
      movingplatform.y += speed;

      if(movingplatform.y <= 25){
        speed = +2;  
      }

      if(movingplatform.y >= 350){
        speed = -2;  
      }

      //moves stodiolight light
    if(setmoveto == true){
      movingstudiolight.x += lightspeed;

      if(movingstudiolight.x <= 2270){
        lightspeed = +2;  
      }
      if(movingstudiolight.x >= 3115){
        lightspeed = -2;  
      }
    }
      //respawn points

     if(birdie.y >= 450){
        birdie.x = birdieRespawnX;
        birdie.y = birdieRespawnY;
        vcam.x = campowerupPositionX;
        powerupscreen.x = campowerupPositionX;
     }

      if(birdie.x >= 533 && birdie.x <= 537){
        birdieRespawnX = 535.75;
        birdieRespawnY = 200.15;
        campowerupPositionX = 519.75
      }

      if(birdie.x >= 2097 && birdie.x <= 2190){
        birdieRespawnX = 2141.5
        birdieRespawnY = 62.55;
        campowerupPositionX = 2155.3;
      }

    //No multiple jumps in air
    if(springen==true){

        birdie.gotoAndStop(laatstejump);
        birdtelleryvertrager+=0.2;
        birdie.y-=15;
        birdie.y+=birdtelleryvertrager;

         if(birdie.y <= 19){
            birdie.y += 15;
         }

        birdtellery++;

        if(isKeyDown(39)==true){
            birdie.x += 5;
            background.x += 1;
            powerupscreen.x += 5
            vcam.x += 5;
            if(birdie.x <= 261.95){
                vcam.x = 275.5;
                powerupscreen.x = 275.5;
                background.x -= 1;
            }
                if(ironbird != true){
                    birdie.gotoAndStop(5);
                }else{birdie.gotoAndStop(13);
                }
        }

        if(isKeyDown(37)==true){
            birdie.x-=5;
            powerupscreen.x-=5;
            vcam.x -= 5;
            background.x -= 1;
            if(birdie.x <= 261.95){
                vcam.x = 275.5;
                powerupscreen.x = 275.5
                background.x += 1;
            }
            birdie.gotoAndStop(6);
        }

        //bird falls down
        if(birdtellery>25){
            birdfatigue == true;
            if(isKeyDown(39)==true){
                birdie.x-=4;
                vcam.x -= 4;
                powerupscreen.x-=4;
            }

            if(isKeyDown(37)==true){
                birdie.x += 4;
                vcam.x += 4;
            }

            birdtelleryvertrager+=0.8;
        }

        //bird can jump again (when on platform)
        if(birdtellery>30){
            springen=false;
        }

    }else{


         if(birdie.y <= 19){
            birdie.y += 15; 
         }
            if(birdfatigue == true){
                birdie.gotoAndStop(7);
            }

            //if right arrow button is pressed
            if(isKeyDown(39)==true){
                birdie.x += movebirdie;

                if(birdie.x >= 261.95){
                    powerupscreen.x += movebirdie;
                    vcam.x += movebirdie;
                    background.x += 0.5;
                }
                if(ironbird != true){
                    birdie.gotoAndStop(2);
                    laatstelook =1;
                }else{birdie.gotoAndStop(11);
                        laatstelook =9;
                    }

                laatstejump =5;
                leftOrrightpressed =1;

            }

            if(isKeyDown(39)==false){
                if (leftOrrightpressed ==1){
                    birdie.gotoAndStop(laatstelook);
                }

            }

            //if left arrow button is pressed
            if(isKeyDown(37)==true){

                birdie.x -= movebirdie;
                background.x -= 0.5;
                powerupscreen.x -= movebirdie;
                vcam.x -= movebirdie;
                if(birdie.x <= 261.95){
                    powerupscreen.x = 275.5
                    vcam.x = 275.5;
                    background.x += 0.5;
                }
                if(ironbird != true){
                    birdie.gotoAndStop(3);
                    laatstelook =4;
                }else{birdie.gotoAndStop(12);
                        laatstelook = 10;
                    }

                laatstejump=6;
                leftOrrightpressed =2;
            }

            if(isKeyDown(37)==false){
                if (leftOrrightpressed ==2){
                    birdie.gotoAndStop(laatstelook);
                }
            }

            //if space button is pressed
            if(isKeyDown(32)==true && springen==false){
                springen=true;  
            }

            if(isKeyDown(17) == true){
                stage.addChild(shit);
                shitlist.push(shit);
                shit.x = birdie.x;
                shit.y = birdie.y;
                birdie.gotoAndStop(14);
            }
            shit.y++;
        }

    if(birdie.hitTestPoint(ironbirdpickup.x,ironbirdpickup.y,true)){
        ironbirdpickup.y = -60;
        powerupscreen.play();
        powerupscreen.visible = true;
        ironbird = true;
        IronManChannel = IronManMusic.play();
        myChannel.stop();
    }

    if(ironbird==true){
        laatstejump = 9;
    }


    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,ctrl_birdie);


    function ctrl_birdie(e:Event){

        //when bird touches one of the platforms, bird stops falling
        for(var a in PlatformArray){
            if(PlatformArray[a].hitTestPoint(birdie.x,birdie.y,true)){
                birdtelleryvertrager=0;
                birdtellery = 0;
                birdie.y-=1;
            }
        }

        for(var b in StudioLightArray){
            if(StudioLightArray[b].hitTestPoint(birdie.x,birdie.y,true)){
                birdtelleryvertrager=0;
                birdtellery = 0;
                birdie.y-=1;
            }
        }

        for(var c in MovingPlatformArray){
            if(MovingPlatformArray[c].hitTestPoint(birdie.x,birdie.y,true)){
                birdtelleryvertrager=0;
                birdtellery = 0;
                birdie.y-=1;
            }
        }

        for(var d in MovingStudioLightArray){
            if(MovingStudioLightArray[d].hitTestPoint(birdie.x,birdie.y,true)){
                birdtelleryvertrager=0;
                birdtellery = 0;
                birdie.y-=1;
                birdie.x = movingstudiolight.x;
                powerupscreen.x = birdie.x
                vcam.x = birdie.x;
                setmoveto = true;
            }
        }

        for(var speaker in SpeakerArray){
            if(SpeakerArray[speaker].hitTestPoint(birdie.x+2,birdie.y,true)){
                birdie.x -= 5;
            }
        }
    }
    //gravity
    vy = 10;
    birdie.y+=vy;
}
//checks if certain key is pressed
function checkKeysDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
    keyArray[event.keyCode][1]=true;
}
function checkKeysUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
    keyArray[event.keyCode][1]=false;
}
function isKeyDown(X){
    return keyArray[X][1];
}
```

If you have some optimizing tips or even found the error in my code, please leave a comment. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Don't have enough time, but on a first look: you have two enter frame loops at the same time, they could be merged. Many for loops, are they really necessary ? Many variables at the top, could you extract some of those into a reusable class(e.g. Birdie, etc.) ? An the most obvious: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't really tell, your code is quite long, but are you adding an event listener for `ENTER_FRAME` inside an event listener for `ENTER_FRAME` to a function which is redefined at each iteration?

If so:

- get `ctrl_birdie` out of the listener (put it at the same level as your other methods),
- call `addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,ctrl_birdie)` only once and
- remove it when you don't need it anymore (if you don't need it anymore at a point).

If it doesn't solve your memory leak, at least it will make your code a bit easier to read.